# Firemonkey iOS access one file from different apps

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

I am writing multiple apps for iPad.  All these apps have some settings in common.  I therefore would like to have one app that handles the settings and write them to a file - the respective apps will then retrieve their settings from this single file.  Is there a way to access one file from different apps on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Keychain may help -> http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/ though a Google search for FireMonkey APIs for the keychain has proven fruitless. At least it could be a starting point.